# Laravel Eloquent - the text of the topic is returning from the joined table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I foreach all `$data` in my blade like `@foreach($data as $d)`, when I use  `$d->text` is returning the 'text' from the `topics.text` not from table `replies.text`

```
public function ShowReplies($userid)
    {
        $data = DB::table('replies')->join('topics', 'topics.id', '=', 'replies.topic')->where('topics.type', '=', 3)->where('replies.isPostDeleted', '=', 0)->where('replies.player', '=', $userid)->orderBy('replies.id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('replies')->with('data', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because topics column '*text*' is override the replies table column '*text*'

you should use Select Column as Alias

```
$data = DB::table('replies')->join('topics', 'topics.id', '=', 'replies.topic')->where('topics.type', '=', 3)->where('replies.isPostDeleted', '=', 0)->where('replies.player', '=', $userid)->orderBy('replies.id', 'desc')->select('replies.text as reply_text')->get();
```

Now use this key('reply_text') to show text